# How to access previously run commands in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I saved my command line by first clicking on it and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and MATLAB saves a .mat file.

Now I want to open it in a text form in order to  remember what I did in my command line the other day.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving a .mat file from the command window saves all of the *variables* that currently exist within your workspace within a binary .mat file. There is no information about the commands that were used to generate these variables in this file format therefore it cannot be automatically extracted from another program.

If you need to get information about what commands were run, you can look at your [command history](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/command-history.html) to see this. If you need to programmatically access this file you can look in MATLAB's [preference directory](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prefdir.html) for the file named `history.m` or `history.xml` on newer versions.

```
type(fullfile(prefdir, 'history.m'))
```

If you need to keep track of what commands you run in the future, you can use [`diary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) at the top of your script or beginning of your session to log all commands and associated command line output to a plain-text log file which would then be accessible to other programs.

```
diary('mylogfile.txt')
```